# Using INSERT INTO across local databases

Tags: c#, t-sql, exception, ado.net, sql-server-express

Caveat: I am new to C# and SQL (less than 2 months with C# and 6 months with SQL)

I have been working on this for a few days, and I am beginning to think I am asking the impossible.

I have two local databases.  The first is a Temp database that receives data from a third party.  This data is in XML format and does have duplicate records in it.

I insert the data into the Temp database and then would like to use INSERT INTO.. to move the unique records into the Final database.

I have created and tested the insert into sql and it works with no problems.  Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO Final.dbo.R_DATA
(C1, C2,..)
SELECT distinct     C1, C2, ...
FROM Temp.dbo.R_DATA
WHERE NOT EXISTS(Select *
FROM Final.dbo.R_DATA
WHERE (R_DATA.C1=Final.dbo.R_DATA.C1))
```

This works.  I have even tried creating a Synonym for Final.dbo.R_DATA, and replaced that in the query - again in SQL Express it also works.
I have also set both queries (with and without the Synonym, as stored procedures, and again they both work from within SQL Express.

I then try to run the same query from C#- using the following.

```
string sqlConnStr = @"DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=W:\SQL\**Temp.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=120;User Instance=True";
FileInfo SQLfile = new FileInfo(@"W:\SQL\MOVETEST.sql");
```

MOVETEST is the sql script I am trying - I converted the above query into a procedure and then placed the procedure in the sql

```
string script = SQLfile.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnStr);
connection.Open();
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
```

I am running this from a form - for testing it is on a button click but I would like it to be part of a longer procedure when / if I get it working. This is for me to see that the connection is open

```
StatusMessage.AppendText(connection.ServerVersion + " " + connection.State);
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
connection.Close();
```

It is at the server.ConnectionContect.ExecuteNonQuery(script); that the error happens - no matter what I try I get an Invalid Object error.  I am thinking that there is no way to insert data from a table in one db to another, or am I missing something.
I think I could make this work by:

1. extract distinct rows from the Temp.R_DATA to a new tempR_DATA
   table in that Temp db.
2. use bulkcopy to move the whole TempR_DATA
   table to the dbo.FINAL
3. connect to the dbo.Final and run a query
   there to insert from the FINAL.dbo.temp.R_DATA into FINAL.dbo.R_DATA
   (using where not exists).

But I would realy like to avoid all of those read and writes, as something tells me it would be slow.

So what am I overlooking? 
Any and all comments are welcome, I have a feeling that this is an issue of concept (how I am trying to do this) rather than syntax etc.

Conrad asked about the exact error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled   Message=Invalid object name '**Final.dbo.RELEASE_DATA'.   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider   ErrorCode=-2146232060   Class=16   LineNumber=3   Number=208   Procedure=MoveRELEASE_DATA   Server=\\.\pipe\37E36041-6FB1-4D\tsql\query   State=1   StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at DataLoader.Imports.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\mydocs\visual studio 2010\Projects\PathFinder\PathFinder\Imports.cs:line 363
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at DataLoader.Program.Main() in c:\mydocs\visual studio 2010\Projects\PathFinder\PathFinder\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)        
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:
```

Here is the error message - same - Invalid Object, I get this whenever I am trying to do the insert across databases.
Thank you.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using the   `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management` objects to execute your sql instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`? Also what is the complete error message that you're getting

Comment: Is `**Final.dbo.RELEASE_DATA` including the `**` the name of your object? Perhaps you should set a breakpoint on the ExecuteNonQuery line and inspect the value of the `script` variable .

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's either something wrong in your script or the way you're reading it. Another option is to just set the CommandText to a literal string e.g. `ExecuteNonQuery(@" INSERT INTO ...")` or `CommandText  = @"INSERT INTO ..."` and then executing it. The `@` symbol will allow you to put line breaks in your literal string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("DataSource=..."))
using (SqlComamnd command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ...";

    connection.Open();
    int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // number of rows inserted
}
```

Also I recommend to wrap the query within a stored procedure.

Comment: Why do you think SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery would work when [ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199350) doesn't?

Comment: @ConradFrix: Why it shall not? If connection string is correct, and there are no security issues, SqlClient with INSERT query cannot do not work.

Comment: Conrad - in response to your first question - no reason other than this is what I started with from the examples I am following.  If System.Data.SqlClient will fix this issue, than I can make the change.

Comment: abatishchev,  I will try this and let you know.

Comment: abatishchev,  No Joy, this code throws the same error - ConradFrix asked about it:

Comment: Sorry, please see my original post - I added the error text there.

Comment: @RichardPhillips: What is the Inner Exception of the exception you get?

Comment: abatishchev,   - this is where that month of c# exp comes in, I do not see any inner exceptions.  the paste above shows blank, and when I look at the debug windows there is nothing to indicate an inner exception.  I gather that this was whatever the item was before the error?  As mentioned the only thing I can find it the attempt to move data from one DB to another - the code (C# and SQL) work perfectly if the insert into is within the same db.  Once I try to go to another DB I get the invalid object error.

Comment: @RichardPhillips: Okay, I got it. Target database `Final` contains no table `dbo.RELEASE_DATA` or there is no such database `Final` at all. Not that you target Temp.mdf file not a real database.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I really appreciate it- I know that there is a DB Final, and that it contains a table dbo.RELEASE_DATA - the two DBs are on the same "express" local server, and located on the same drive, in the same folder, I can see that both contain the table RELEASE_DATA (in my example I used R_DATA) and that both have the same fields - Final is a copy of Temp with certain fields set as PK etc.

Comment: As mentioned this error only crops up when crossing from one DB to another, in fact I can run the query (with copies of the tables in each ie R_D_Final, and R_D_Temp in the same database (either one) and it works.  I have run your script this way refeing to an sql script described as above and perfect.  UNTIL I try to cross from one DB to another.

Comment: @RichardPhillips: I think that multiple database queriy can be run against real database only, not against a file that afaik can containjust  1 database. Can you publish your files as real databases onto the server?

Comment: Not at this time, presently due to security these are on a drive that gets locked up every night.  I know there are a whole host of issues (back-up etc) that this brings up.  But these are the risks and this is so far the only accepted way to work with it.

Comment: Again - Thank you very much, I will look at the bulk copy options.  I think I can get it to work - if I can use a "filter" on the write side of the equation.

Comment: I checked the solution as it does work - it will copy data from one table to another - or run a stored procedure - as long as it is all within one database - if working with sql express.